# The speed of back to the previous activity is low in Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to go back to the previous activity.
I use the 
`finish` or `onBackPressed` method
Using these methods, it returns to the previous page, but after a few seconds
Of course, the phone's back button is fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized my mistake
When this function is executed in **MainActivity**, it causes the main program page to restart